# Coil pack firing

Tags: mercury

Upper right and lower right side of my new coil pack isn't firing  have replaced spark plugs and wires along with new coil pack and the idle air control sensor and still no fire out of my coil pack

Comment: Add specific info about your car. Model, engine size etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.